# CSS: Making all column heights the same even though various c

Tags: html, css

```
<div id='row1'>
    <div id='column1'>This is a couple of lines long</div>
    <div id='column2'>This column can be varying in length, so this could go on for 5 lines or 20 lines</div>
    <div id='column3'>This is a another column of a few lines</div>
</div>
```

row1 is 960 wide.
Each column is 310 wide and is set display:inline-block (also with a border).

I need all three columns to be the same height taking into account the varying height of column 2.  I've tried all columns as height:100%, but I cannot set the height of row1 
because I need this to expand depending on how much content is in column 2.

How can I get all three columns to display the same height, but that height dictated by the dynamic content of column 2?

```
  Col1      Col2     Col3
****************************
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
|        |        |        |
****************************
```

Comment: You probably want to use HTML tables: http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

Comment: Why you not using [<table>](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp) which always keeps all collumn with the same height?

Answer (score 2):

Use tables for this, far easier and no hacks needed ...

```
<table border="1" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Col 1</td>
            <td>Col 2</td>
            <td>Col 3</td>  
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Table Cell</td>
            <td>Table Cell</td>
            <td>Table Cell</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dont care about ie7 support you can use your current html with

```
#row1 div { 
display:table-cell; 
width:200px; 
padding:0 15px; 
border:1px solid #efefef;
}
```

Ideally you would wrap your code in another div and make use of display:table; and display:table-row;

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y4Gub/

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you may be looking for, similar to chris' answer.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="column">column 1</div>
    <div class="column">column 2</div>
    <div class="column">column 3</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    width: 960px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
.column, .column, .column {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    width: 310px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

Here is a live JSFiddle file to test (http://jsfiddle.net/ULQwf/364/)